# split string through strtok in c language

Tags: c, string, tokenize

I am splitting string through strtok but something different happen e.g

```
 *tok =strtok(string,"\r\n");
```

strtok when found only `\r` then it split string not whole `\r\n` , I want string should be splited only when whole string occur in data `\r\n` ;

Comment: The 2nd argument to `strtok` is a series of characters to split on, for example `strtok(string, ";,")` will split on the first `,` or `;`.

Comment: is there any possibility so that splitting occur on whole string . single character

Comment: use `strstr` in a loop

Answer (score 2):

To split a string using multiple character you can use [`strstr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr) in a loop

Just repeatedly call `strstr` to find occurrences of your boundary string.

After you get a result, advance the pointer by the length of the substring and repeat the search again.

This is an ugly example but I think it does what you need

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char buffer[128];
  char *str ="This is a long text \r\n with \r\nmany carriage returns,\
  I hate \r\n just this\r\n nothing else\r\n";

  char *token="\r\n";

  int l=strlen(str);
  char *start,*p;
  start=str;

  p= strstr (str,token);
  while(p)
  {
     strncpy( buffer,str, p-str);
     buffer[p-str] ='\0';

     printf("%s\n",buffer);

     str=p+strlen(token);

     if((str-start) >= l)
        break;

     p= strstr (str,token);
 }
 if(!p)
   printf("%s\n",str);
 return 0;
}
```

See **[HERE](http://ideone.com/2dhSfn)**

PS:If anybody want, please edit the code, to make it bit better.

Comment: well its good example . upto 70% my problem is solved . but can you please check it with this string and then see behaviour of the program ."This is a long \r text \r\n with \r\n many carriage returns,\
  I hate \r\n just this\r\n nothing else\r\n";

Comment: If I understood your question, I believe 100% of your problem is solved.   Having just run the code I posted a few hours ago replacing all "ggg" with "\r\n",  I produced the image I will edit the post with above.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to split a string based on the occurrence of a substring (such as "\r\n") you will have to use string search functions such as char * strstr(,).    strstr() will return a pointer to the matched sub-string.  You can then then manipulate the resulting string at that point to remove strlen("\r\n") bytes from the resultant, and continue your search.

[EDITED]  from an excellent post ***[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408170/for-string-find-and-replace)*** with a reference to excellent code by ***[this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/325446/m-qayyum)***

m-qayyums code is called in a loop to show you how you can look for (and replace) multiple occurrences of a sub-string with another sub-string, even an empty string using strstr(,) et. al.

```
#include <ansi_c.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *replace_str(char *str, char *orig, char *rep);

int main ()
{
    char origStr[]={"this is anggg originalggg lineggg ogggf texgggt"};
    char newString[]={"this is anggg originalggg lineggg ogggf texgggt"};


    sprintf(newString, "%s", origStr);
    while(strstr(newString, "ggg"))
    {
        sprintf(newString, "%s", replace_str(newString, "ggg", ""));
    }
    printf("Original String:  %s\n", origStr);
    printf("New      String:  %s\n", newString);

    getchar();

    return 0;
}


char *replace_str(char *str, char *orig, char *rep)
{
  static char buffer[4096];
  char *p;

  if(!(p = strstr(str, orig)))  // Is 'orig' even in 'str'?
    return str;

  strncpy(buffer, str, p-str); // Copy characters from 'str' start to 'orig' st$
  buffer[p-str] = '\0';

  sprintf(buffer+(p-str), "%s%s", rep, p+strlen(orig));

  return buffer;
}
```

[EDIT_2]  replacing "ggg" with "\r\n" I got this result using the code above:

[image]

Comment: can you please give some example it will be realy apreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a *nix system, you could use the POSIX Regex library to achieve this result, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085083/regular-expressions-in-c-examples).

Answer (score -1):

```
/* strtok example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] ="- This, a sample string.";
  char * pch;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str," ,.-");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Splitting string "- This, a sample string." into tokens:
This
a
sample
string
```

Comment: thanks man . can yo please tell about any possiblility so that string split on the occurance of the whole string .??? i realy need this

Comment: @P0W - Plagiarism is the highest form of flattery.  And it is illustrative, (kind of) relevant, and salient.  _(Kind of)_ because it really does not answer the question of how to break a string at every occurrence of a ***sub-string***.