# Encode HTML Characters in C

Tags: c

I am reading data over a socket and parsing it with LibXML.

The problem that I am currently having is that sometimes there is a web link in the data which breaks the parser.

`http://example.com/?key=value&key2=value`

Is there any way to convert that to html characters?

Something like the above to

`http://example.com/?key=value&amp;key2=value`

Example of socket data:

`<node link="http://example.com/?key=value&key2=value" />`

EDIT:
[Found a solution that works for my problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408170/for-string-find-and-replace/12546318#12546318)

Comment: Am I blind or aren't there any differences between the two examples?

Comment: The two examples are identical, aren't they!!

Comment: Use backticks ` or else the amp won't show.

Comment: the markup translates the html codes. Made them into code blocks

Comment: it is relatively easy to cook yourself a function. Basically what you need is a search and replace.

Comment: html characters starts with an '&' and ends with ';' you either have to parse the string, or iterate all html charaters table and do find replace. here is [the html table](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm). pay intention some characters may be in unicode

Comment: @milevyo: You know that. I know that. OP probably knows that. The problem is his source failed to encode URLs correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a nice solution using the code from
[Find and Replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408170/for-string-find-and-replace/12546318#12546318) that uses a Find and Replace method suggested by bolov.

```
retval = str_replace(message, size, "&", "&amp;");
if (!retval) {
    printf("Not enough room to replace & with `&amp;'\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to do a pre-filter here. Contrary to other indications, search and replace just won't cut it. Consider your search side is &, which matches too much.

Construct the following finite state machine:

```
NORMAL:
    if next matches "<" then TAG

TAG:
    if next matches "![CDATA[" then CDATA
    TAGSCAN

TAGSCAN:
    if next matches whitespace then TAGSCAN2
    if next matches > or next matches /> then NORMAL

TAGSCAN2:
    if next matches whitespace then TAGSCAN2
    if next matches SRC= or next matches HREF= then URL
    TAGSCAN

URL:
   we found an attribute with a URL in it. Do your search and replace
   on the contents of the URL attribute value, advance past the URL and
   go back to TAGSCAN

CDATA:
   if next doesn't match ]]> then CDATA
   NORMAL
```

Comment: "![CDATA["  in url??? he want just to reformat the urls, not to parse the file content.

Comment: But <A HREF inside CDATA isn't a link.